# what does the below statement do?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->dob = '20-03-1999';
$profile->bio = 'A professional programmer.';

$user = User::find(1);
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

what does `User::find(1)` do ?
i am new to laravel.

Comment: What have you tried to get an answer for that question? Usually, such stuff is widely covered in tutorials

Comment: It will find user with id = 1 and return an instance of `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It perform a search query like

```
select * from <user model table> where <primary key> = 1
```

and the associate all the table's property to the $user instance.

Note:

1. Table name in 99% of cases is users (check your model file app\Models\User in Laravel 8)
2. Primary key in 99% of cases is id, still check your model file

---

The complete statement wil get the user with ID = 1 from database and save a profile that has been just created